# Geo nodes parse string to geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am looking for a solution where there is a string: for example "123456" that will add the corresponding instances from a collection to the scene.

So I have a collection with 10 objects.

When I enter the string 1424, it would spit out instances 1, 4, 2 and another 4.

With string length I thought I knew how many times I can run a repeat zone that selects the correct instance but I am having trouble to join all the geometry in the end. So all the instances are shown instead of only the last one...

Any help?

- EDIT-

Below are some pictures:
[image: This geo nodes setup show one of the 4 objects in the object catalog.]

Can parse a string, for example "31" so it would show object 3 and object 1.

I can use the repeat function and string length run the repeat function the correct amount of times:
[image]

But how can I parse this string and also how can I make the repeat zon add the instances one at a time?

I want to add this file but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Would you mind showing what you already did or even better upload a file? I don't know what your goal is or what "spit out instances" means in this case. It would be easier to see what your trouble with joining is if we knew how you implemented that.

Comment: I'd be okay if you shared a picture. not everyone would open up a file, but most times a picture gives enough information (if you simply the example, of it's a simple example to begin with - which it should be in your case.

Comment: I edited the post with pictures. I hope this is a bit clearer now?

Comment: Even if you can slice parts of the string, I don't think there is a node that allows to convert a character into an integer.

Comment: Ok, would there be another way of choosing different objects from a collection?

Answer (score 1):

[image][image]

With the Repeat Zone you can compare each character of the string to the string representation of the digits, switching for the correct integer representation. In each step you store the results in the ID of a point and join it to a point cloud containing all previous results. This point cloud will serve as a list.

[image]

After that you use the digits output to pick the instance.

---

[image] $\small\text{Blender 4.0}$

Comment: Thank youuuu, this works